# How to extract title of hrefs using BS4?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing wikipedia, and I need to get **title** from `href` on the page. I have this code to get only links,but I have no idea how I can get only `titles`.

```
response = requests.get(url=url_start)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        status_code = response.status_code
        if status_code == 200:
            for link in soup.find(id="bodyContent").findAll("a"):
                if "/wiki/" in link['href']:
                    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: have you tried `link['title']`?

Comment: @Yarin_007 yes i have, but when i do this, i got only first titles from page, even if i changed **id**, probably i use incorrect id for this,but maybe no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

Select your elements more specific (may use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)) and extract value of attribute with `get('title)` - In case that there is no title this will give you `None`:

```
[a.get('title') for a in soup.select('#bodyContent a[href*="/wiki/"]')]
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python').content)

[a.get('title') for a in soup.select('#bodyContent a[href*="/wiki/"]')]
```

##### Output

```
['Altgriechische Sprache', 'Python (Mythologie)', 'Pythons', 'Eigentliche Pythons', 'Python (Programmiersprache)', 'Monty Python', 'Python (Schiff, 1935)', 'Peithon', 'Python Vehicles Australia', 'Python (Töpfer)', 'Python (Vasenmaler)', 'Paestanische Vasenmalerei', 'Georges Python', 'Valentine Python', 'Python (Efteling)', 'Colt Python', 'Knicklenker (Fahrrad)', 'Python-3', 'Python-4', 'Python-5', 'wikt:Python', 'Pythia', 'Wikipedia:Begriffsklärung', 'Wikipedia:Kategorien', 'Kategorie:Begriffsklärung']
```